# Is the Python assert message evaluated if the assertion passes

Tags: python, assert, assertion

Let's say I have an `assert` statement with a computationally heavy error message (e.g. makes several network or database calls).

```
assert x == 5, f"Some computationally heavy message here: {requests.get('xxx')}"
```

I could also write this code using an if statement:

```
if x != 5:
    raise AssertionError(f"Some computationally heavy message here: {requests.get('xxx')}")
```

I know the latter option will only evaluate the error message if `x != 5`. What about the former option? I would assume so but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can easily set up a test case with a print statement and check it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the expression after the `,` is not evaluated if the asserted condition is true:

```
>>> assert 1 == 5, foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

But:

```
>>> assert 5 == 5, foo
```

does not raise a `NameError`.

According to the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement),

> The extended form, `assert expression1, expression2`, is equivalent to
>
> ```
> if __debug__:
>     if not expression1: raise AssertionError(expression2)
> ```

and an [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if)

> […] selects exactly one of the suites by evaluating the expressions one
> by one until one is found to be true […]; then that suite is executed
> **(and no other part of the if statement is executed or evaluated)**

So it seems this is the required behaviour.

Comment: Clever way to test it out.  Bravo!